# I need help to clean up a script that blocks rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below works but requires too much time to work. In fact, the script cannot finish the code, since the time to process the script has passed several times.
I gladly received help to fine-tune this code
The script was created to block (grouped) rows, if a value is entered in column E. This code is activated every 24 hours as a trigger.
Objective: The worksheet with 1000 rows, is accessible to 250 people, whether or not registered with a google account, and serves to record recreational tennis matches.

```
  var MaxRow = Sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();

  var RowCount = 1;

  var Cell = Sheet.getRange("D"+ RowCount);

  var CellValue =  Cell.getValue();

  var BlockStart = 0;

  var BlockEnd = 0;

  var LockRange = Sheet.getRange(59,6,1,2); 

  for (RowCount = 4; RowCount <= MaxRow ; RowCount++) { 

    Cell = Sheet.getRange("D"+ RowCount);

    CellValue =  Cell.getValue();

    if (CellValue != "") { 

     if (BlockStart == 0) { 

       BlockStart = RowCount;

       BlockEnd = RowCount;

     }

     else {

       BlockEnd = RowCount;

     }          

   }

   else {

     if (BlockStart > 0) {

       LockRange = Sheet.getRange(BlockStart,6,BlockEnd-BlockStart + 1,2);

       var Protection = LockRange.protect().setDescription('Rows ' + 
       BlockStart + ' To ' + BlockEnd +  ' Protected');

       Protection.removeEditors(Protection.getEditors());

       BlockStart = 0;

       BlockEnd = 0;

      }  
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are better off on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange with this question - SO is for issues, not code optimization. That said, `getRange()` and `getValue()` are I/O methods and thus the slowest, therefore you need to avoid putting them into loops. Batch getters like `getValues()` will allow you to work on an Array of values directly (as you need to check `CellValue`) and save you a bunch of runtime

Answer (score 2):

Without a complete function I can't really figure out what you're trying to do.  But let's say that you want to read the values in column D from line 4 to the bottom of data, then here's a simple and fast way to do it.  This isn't the only way.  But it's a lot faster than using getValue() on each row.  This will probably run about 10000 times faster.

```
function getDataInColumnD() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(4,4,Sheet.getLastRow()-3,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) { 
    var value=vA[i][0];
    var row=i+4;
    Logger.log('col: 4, row: %s, value: %s',row,value);
  }
}
```